# Kotlin JUnit5 tests using Bazel target not found

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin, bazel

I have a Bazel project in Kotlin and I am trying to run unit tests with JUnit 5.
Here are my targets:

```
kt_jvm_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/kotlin/**/*.kt"]),
)

kt_jvm_test(
    name = "tests",
    main_class = "org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher",
    args = [
        "--select-package=com.acme",
    ],
    srcs = glob(["src/test/kotlin/**/*.kt"]),
    deps = [
        ":lib",
        "@maven//:org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_api",
        "@maven//:org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_engine",
        "@maven//:org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_params",
        "@maven//:org_junit_platform_junit_platform_console",
    ],
)
```

When I run `bazel run //:tests`, I get this output:

```
Thanks for using JUnit! Support its development at https://junit.org/sponsoring

╷
└─ JUnit Jupiter ✔

Test run finished after 43 ms
[         1 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         1 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

As you see, no tests are found. What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. My test classes' name does not match `*Test.kt` pattern, but `*Should.kt`. When I changed their name to match `*Test.kt`, tests were found are everything started working.

I will accept this answer as the correct, however, if anybody knows how can I keep my test classes naming style and make it work, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JUnit 5 Document](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher), ConsoleLauncher has the following options,

```
  -n, --include-classname=PATTERN
                             Provide a regular expression to include only classes whose
                               fully qualified names match. To avoid loading classes
                               unnecessarily, the default pattern only includes class
                               names that begin with "Test" or end with "Test" or
                               "Tests". When this option is repeated, all patterns will
                               be combined using OR semantics. Default: [^(Test.*|.+[.$]
                               Test.*|.*Tests?)$]
  -N, --exclude-classname=PATTERN
                             Provide a regular expression to exclude those classes whose
                               fully qualified names match. When this option is repeated,
                               all patterns will be combined using OR semantics.
      --include-package=PKG  Provide a package to be included in the test run. This
                               option can be repeated.
      --exclude-package=PKG  Provide a package to be excluded from the test run. This
                               option can be repeated.
  -t, --include-tag=TAG      Provide a tag or tag expression to include only tests whose
                               tags match. When this option is repeated, all patterns
                               will be combined using OR semantics.
  -T, --exclude-tag=TAG      Provide a tag or tag expression to exclude those tests whose
                               tags match. When this option is repeated, all patterns
                               will be combined using OR semantics.
  -e, --include-engine=ID    Provide the ID of an engine to be included in the test run.
                               This option can be repeated.
  -E, --exclude-engine=ID    Provide the ID of an engine to be excluded from the test
                               run. This option can be repeated.
```